# How to show previous days as read only?

Tags: php, mysql

Can someone pls look into code below and tell me what am i doing wrong. What i am trying to accomplish is to make previous days read-only,that cant be change if is in past and when time given is also passed.Data is saved in mysql table (sorry for my poor english ) Thank you

```
<?php 
require_once '../../configuratie.php'; 

include template. 'header.php';

date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Amsterdam');
$time=date('Hi'); 
$datum = isset($_GET['datum']) ? $_GET['datum'] : date('Y-m-d ');
$prevDay = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($datum .' -1 day'));
$currentDay = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($datum .' now'));
$nextDay = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($datum .' +1 day'));

$row = $conn->prepare(" SELECT * FROM tabelPL WHERE aangemaakt >= '".$currentDay."' order by aangemaakt ");
$row->execute();
$row = $row->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if(isset($_POST['submit_ochtend'])) {   
    $P20 = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'P20', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
```

Comment: @Strawberry thanks for edit :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You main problem appears to be here:

```
<?php if ( ($time >= "0600") && ($time <= "1400") === $prevDay)  : ?>
```

`($time <= "1400")` will evaluate as True or False, which you are trying to compare to a date.

Instead `$currentDay` needs to be evaluated separately against the server date like this.

```
<?php if ( ($time >= "0600") && ($time <= "1400") && date("Y-m-d") == $currentDay)  : ?>
```

Also, you don't need to make that acception for `!empty($row['P20']`. Placeholder Text only shows up when there is not content; so, you can always include it, and the browser will figure out if you need it.  So, your whole output can be simplified to look like:

```
<?php 
    if (($time >= "0600") && ($time <= "1400") && (date("Y-m-d") == $currentDay)) {    
        echo'<textarea id="P20_ocht" name="P20" class="form-control animated" placeholder="Type hier uw tekst">'.$row['P20'].'</textarea>';
    } else {
        echo'<textarea id="P20_ocht" name="P20" class="form-control animated" placeholder="Type hier uw tekst" readonly>'.$row['P20'].'</textarea>';
    } 
?>
```

Last thing to consider is security.  Just because you add a readonly tag does not mean someone can't edit the HTML in their browser to remove it; so, if this is a concern, you want to also make an exception in your PHP or SQL to throw out UPDATE requests for past dates which might look something like this:

```
$update_query = "UPDATE tabelPL SET P20 = ?, aangemaakt = NOW() WHERE id = ? AND aangemaakt >= ? LIMIT 1"; 
$stmt = $conn->prepare($update_query);
    $stmt->bindParam(1, $P20, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(2, $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindParam(3, $currentDay, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->execute();
```

Comment: Hi .. your fix is great. but if i want to current day from 06:00 until 1400 to be able to save and edit between that time and only at current day (not previous days) what i need to change in code you provide?? @Nosajimiki

Comment: Ah, that makes a lot more since. I've modified the answer accordingly.

Comment: Hi .. is it possible with singel submit button to INSERT data in mysql database and when is inserted to UPDATE same on a current day only?? I managed to insert but when i want to update it makes a new row inside db.. any suggestions how to fix this.. ?? thank u..

Comment: You can use all the date from your input form to run as many queries as you wish, just do one query for the insert, then do another for the update.  Just make sure that you put in some error detection to make sure that the update only runs if the insert does not return an error.

Comment: I tried that .. but stil when its insert ok but when i make change for current day its insert new row inside database for same day ... the code above is somewhere wrong ... can u point out where that mistake is please...

Comment: This is a bit off topic from your original question. You should ask this as a new question.  StackOverflow moderators prefer a 1-problem per question format because it makes it easier for Search Engines to help future readers find solutions to problems that have been solved before.

Comment: i made an new question ... thank u for your help en advice .. i hoop that someone can help me ...